# How do I count the number of rows returned by subquery?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I want to do something like this:

```
select count(*) from (select ...)
```

(As it would be in SQL), but in JPA.

Any ideas on how I would do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick (If you want to use JPA criteria API):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();  
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);

//Selecting the count
query.select(cb.count(root));

//Create your search criteria
Criteria criteria = ...

//Adding search criteria   
query.where(criteria);

Long count = getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

On the other hand, if you want to use JP-QL, the following code should do the trick:

```
//Add the where condition to the end of the query
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select count(*) from Entity entity where...")
Long count = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Problem is that I wanted to get the count of returned rows of a subquery. It seems that it is not possible because subqueries can not be used like that in JPA

Comment: This doesn't answer the concrete question at all. The OP is asking how to count the results of a subquery, not how to count the results of a query.

Comment: It does not work if zero rows returned. Hibernate crushes with `javax.persistence.NoResultException`

Answer (score 35):

I stumbled upon this issue as well. I would ultimately like to execute the following JPQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(u)
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT u
   FROM User u
   JOIN u.roles r
   WHERE r.id IN (1)
)
```

But this wasn't possible, also not with criteria API. Research taught that this was just a design limitation in JPA. The JPA spec states that subqueries are only supported in `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses (and thus not in the `FROM`).

Rewriting the query in the following JPQL form:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(u)
FROM User u
WHERE u IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT u
   FROM User u
   JOIN u.roles r
   WHERE r.id IN (1)
)
```

using the JPA Criteria API like as follows:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<User> u = query.from(User.class);
Subquery<User> subquery = query.subquery(User.class);
Root<User> u_ = subquery.from(User.class);
subquery.select(u_).distinct(true).where(u_.join("roles").get("id").in(Arrays.asList(1L)));
query.select(cb.count(u)).where(cb.in(u).value(subquery));
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
// ...
```

has solved the functional requirement for me. This should also give you sufficient insight into solving your particular functional requirement.

Comment: you can't use this approach if you want to count result of aggregating query

Comment: @Martin What approach would you suggest to DISTINCT COUNT from arbitrary CriteriaQuery?

Comment: @svlada, I found no effective solution, only to return all rows and count them on the application server.

Comment: @Martin In that case I believe that only option is to go plain JDBC query.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following snippet to count rows for a given Criteria Query:

```
public static Query createNativeCountQuery(EntityManager em, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery) {
  org.hibernate.query.Query<?> hibernateQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class);
  String hqlQuery = hibernateQuery.getQueryString();

  QueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
  QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(
    hqlQuery,
    hqlQuery,
    Collections.emptyMap(),
    em.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class),
    null
  );
  queryTranslator.compile(Collections.emptyMap(), false);

  String sqlCountQueryTemplate = "select count(*) from (%s)";
  String sqlCountQuery = String.format(sqlCountQueryTemplate, queryTranslator.getSQLString());

  Query nativeCountQuery = em.createNativeQuery(sqlCountQuery);

  Map<Integer, Object> positionalParamBindings = getPositionalParamBindingsFromNamedParams(hibernateQuery);
  positionalParamBindings.forEach(nativeCountQuery::setParameter);

  return nativeCountQuery;
}

private static Map<Integer, Object> getPositionalParamBindingsFromNamedParams(org.hibernate.query.Query<?> hibernateQuery) {
  Map<Integer, Object> bindings = new HashMap<>();

  for (var namedParam : hibernateQuery.getParameterMetadata().getNamedParameters()) {
    for (int location : namedParam.getSourceLocations()) {
      bindings.put(location + 1, hibernateQuery.getParameterValue(namedParam.getName()));
    }
  }

  return bindings;
}
```

Comment: it works except for enums and list params

Comment: Does not work for me: `ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias`. And if I add an alias manually to `sqlCountQueryTemplate` it will throw another error: `Invalid endian flag value encountered.`

Comment: Second error was caused indeed by enum parameter. Workaround: `if (parameterValue.getClass().isEnum()) { parameterValue = parameterValue.toString(); }` But only works if enums are saved as string in db.

Comment: For using it with List params, the criteria filter must be written as:
`root.("ref").in(<List>)`
instead of
`criteriaBuilder.in(root.("ref")).value(<List>)`
This way it seems to be working fine for me