# How can I build a JPA query to count the number of results of an arbitrary CriteriaQuery?

Tags: java, jpa

I have an arbitrary JPA criteria query. I would like to know how many results that query would produce without transferring all the results from the database.

So basically I would like to create a query

```
select count(*) from (<the arbitrary criteria query>)
```

The problem is that either I don't know how to create a `SubQuery` from the original `CriteriaQuery` when implementing this like:

```
CriteriaQuery<Integer> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
criteriaBuilder.count(criteriaQuery);
```

Or I'm missing another way to implement it.

How can I do this using JPA?

**Edit:**
This is not a duplicate of [How do I count the number of rows returned by subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423937), because I already have a CriteriaQuery instance at hand, that I would like to incorporate into a new query or modify. The other question is about crafting a query from scratch. The point this question is about is how to use the `CriteriaQuery` instance I already have at hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of rows returned by subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423937/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-subquery)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a CriteriaQuery as a Subquery.

One way to count the number of rows is to use the `getResultList()` method.

```
return criteriaBuilder.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList().size()
```

In my opinion, this is not an optimal solution, but works when you expect small result list. Otherwise you need to rewrite your existing CriteriaQuery as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2884378/7454754).