# JPA Criteria API: select count(*) from subquery with joins and group by for pagination implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

I want to implement a pagination feature in a list of products returned from database. So I need to known the total results of the query.

Database tables are:

```
PRODUCT TABLE             
-----------------------------
ID             NAME
-------------- --------------
1              Product 1
2              Product 2

PRODUCT SUPPLIER TABLE
--------------------------------------------
ID             PRODUCT ID     PRICE
-------------- -------------- --------------
1              1              35
2              1              30
3              2              70
4              2              75
```

The desire result is a list of products with the minimum price of the different suppliers.

```
Product 1    30
Product 2    70
```

Main query should be something like:

```sql
select p.name, min(ps.price) from product
inner join product_supplier ps on ps.product_id = p.id
group by p.name
```

So count query should be something like:

```sql
select count(*) from (
   select p.name, min(ps.price) from product
   inner join product_supplier ps on ps.product_id = p.id
   group by p.name
)
```

Code I'am using to get paginated results is:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> tupleQuery = cb.createTupleQuery();

Root<product> product = tupleQuery.from(product.class);
Join<product, productSupplier> productSuppliers = product.join("productSuppliers");

tupleQuery.multiselect(
   product,
   cb.min(productSuppliers.get("price")).alias("price")
);
tupleQuery.groupBy(product);
tupleQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(product.get("name")));

TypedQuery<Tuple> query = entityManager
                            .createQuery(tupleQuery)
                            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
                            .setFirstResult(Long.valueOf(pageable.getOffset()).intValue());

List<Tuple> products = query.getResultList();
for (Tuple productResult : products) {
   Product product = productResult.get(product);
   Double minPrice = (Double)productResult.get("price");
   ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO(product, minPrice);  
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get count from the main query. Code I'm using is:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class)
    
Root<Product> product = countQuery.from(Product.class);
Join<Product, ProductSupplier> productSuppliers = product.join("productSuppliers");
    
countQuery.groupBy(product);
countQuery.select(cb.count(product));

long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

But it produces the following SQL:

```sql
select
   count(product0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
from
   pu_products product0_ 
inner join
   pu_product_suppliers productsu1_ 
      on product0_.id=productsu1_.product_id
group by
   product0_.id
```

Returning more than one result, throwing the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 31
```

So I don't know how to get it work.

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to achieve your requirement?

Comment: Finally I did what I wrote in the answer, using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323540/6087757)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that is not possible to do a `select count (*) from` from an aggregated query via Criteria API:

- [Discussion in discourse.hibernate.org](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/get-the-total-result-size-of-a-query-with-aggregations-and-groupping/1381/4)
- [You can use a subquery only in your WHERE but not in the SELECT or FROM clause](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/)

So finally I've applied **this solution** found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323540/6087757):

- After build the query via Criteria API, get the *final query string*.
- Wrap it with `select count(*) from ({final_query_string})`.
- Create a Native Query with the result of wrapping the *final query string* with the `select count (*) from`.

Full code of this **solution** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323540/6087757) from [@fliX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419480/flix).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What about a namedquery like this one :

```
select count(distinct ps.product) from product_supplier ps where ps.price is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @grigouille . The idea behind using Criteria API is to build a query dynamically, adding where, and, or, ... clauses by Predicate interface.

So in that scenario a "static" named query can't be used.